# How can I archive web pages linked to in my Delicious bookmarks?

Tags: bookmarks, archiving, backup, delicious, webarchive

I'm looking for ways to quickly backup the web pages I have collected in my Delicious Bookmarks, to guard against linkrot, etc. The most efficient method I've come up with so far would be to export my Delicious bookmarks into a single web page/HTML format and then use [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) to capture the HTML from the source pages (obviously, I would have to experiment with link depth, etc. and limit some of the file types I'm downloading.

Can anyone else think of a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTrack method that you have described is the fastest way to cache the webpages because it is automated.

If you don't have many webpages to cache, you can save individual webpages using your browser's Save As feature. Opera and Internet Explorer can save an [MHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML) archive of a webpage in a single MHT file. You could try to write a script to try to automate this.

There are also free, alternative bookmarking services that support webpage caching:

- Clipboard: https://clipboard.com/
- Evernote: http://evernote.com/webclipper/
- Historious (300): http://historio.us/
- Diigo (30): http://www.diigo.com/

Clipboard is the best that I have found because it preserves the webpage styling and formatting. Many other free webpage caching services strip everything and leave only plain text.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [pinboard](http://www.pinboard.in/), although it is not free.  There is a one time fee of $9.41 to sign up, and an [archival account](http://www.pinboard.in/tour/#archive) (which is what you would need) costs $25 per year.  Finally, you can set pinboard to copy links from your [delicious](http://www.delicious.com/) account (although I suspect it will only work with your public delicious bookmarks).  This would give you the functionality you seem to be looking for - for a price.  Obviously if you're looking for a free solution it's not the answer.