# Creates PDF from Bookmarks

Tags: bookmarks

I have a large list of bookmarks in google chrome, firefox, and internet explorer.  I have sites bookmarked from years ago that are no longer available.  How can I archive the sites I have bookmarked as a PDF?  I wanted to do something like what readability does to strip the site down to basic content.  Then it would be great to tag them according to how my bookmarks are organized in the bookmarks list.  Is there a tool that can accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want to completely download the site you have bookmarked but in PDF format ? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is what I would like to do.  That way I still have the information even if the website goes offline.

Comment: I'd suggest that u download the entire site using httrack software rather than converting into PDF. By this you preserve the navigation to different pages. By converting to PDF u lose the ability to navigate through the site as u would do when ur online

Comment: If I do this how could I then get these sites into a program like evernote?  Is there any way to automate opening a site saving it in a directory structure based on the bookmarks structure (from firefox or chrome)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/335277/how-can-i-archive-web-pages-linked-to-in-my-delicious-bookmarks4 try this